# compare argv[1][i] arrays C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to compare arrays in an argument

can some tell me why this part of code is wrong

```
{
for(int i=0;i<strlen(argv[3]);i++)
    if(strcmp((argv[3][i]),"c")==0){
        cout<<"C"<<endl;
        return (0);
    }
```

thanks.....

Comment: Horrible formatting, and you don't even explain what "wrong" is or does.

Comment: What is the type of argv? So what is the type of argv[3][i]? And what type is strcmp expecting?

Comment: argv[3][i] is a array in the string argv[3] so like kingsindian said it shouldn't work but is there any alternate method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(strcmp((argv[3][i]),"c")==0)
```

This line is wrong.

argv[3][i] is a character, not a string. You probably want :

```
if(argv[3][i]=='c')
```

Comment: tried that also but didn't work

Comment: when tried what you say "it says operand types are incompatible"

Comment: @AshFernando: Did you try it exactly as it appears here, `'c'` with single quotes to denote a character literal, not `"c"` with double quotes to denote a string literal? (I'm assuming that `argv` has its conventional meaning of the array of strings passed as the second argument of `main`; if it's something else, then you need to tell us what it is).

Comment: sorry i had used double quotes worlks with single quotes thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what u wanted to try.

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(argv[3]);i++)
{
if(argv[3][i]=='c')
   {
     cout<<"\n found c";

    }
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` compares strings, not characters. You want `==` to compare characters.

Comment: corrected comparison...